How to implement comprehensive visitor profiling similar to LeadFeeder?
How to implement comprehensive visitor profiling similar to LeadFeeder?
I'm trying to implement a visitor profiling system for my website, similar to what LeadFeeder offers. I need to gather the following information for each visitor:

Location
IP Address
Visitor Name
Visitor Email
Visitor LinkedIn profile
Visitor Company information

What I've tried
I've attempted to use IPInfo to gather some of this data, but I've found that in most cases, it only provides the ISP address, which isn't sufficient for my needs.
My question
What services or techniques can I use to gather more comprehensive visitor information? I'm particularly interested in solutions that can provide:

More accurate location data
Company information
Professional details like LinkedIn profiles

Are there any APIs or services specifically designed for this kind of visitor profiling? How can I implement this functionality in a way that's both effective and respectful of privacy laws?
Additional context

This is for a B2B website, so the focus is on professional/company information rather than personal data.
I'm open to both free and paid solutions.
Any insights on the legal considerations for this kind of data collection would also be appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any guidance or suggestions!
